# XML content not showing up when using chrome browser

Tags: html, xml, dom, browser, dtd

I have one xml file with below content:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend</body>
</note>
```

and corresponding html file as below:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>W3Schools Internal Note</h1>
<div>
<b>To:</b> <span id="to"></span><br />
<b>From:</b> <span id="from"></span><br />
<b>Message:</b> <span id="message"></span>
</div>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("from").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("from")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

when I run the html file on chrome browser I am not able to view the whole content. Below is what I see in the Chrome Browser

```
To: 

    From: 

    Message:
```

But when I run in firefox browser I get output as expected:

```
 To: Tove
From: Jani
Message: Don't forget me this weekend
```

Question 1: Can some one explain me this behavior.

Comment: Have you tried using `xmlhttp.responseText` instead of `xmlhttp.responseXML`?  The following post mentions this as a possible cause for your problem with Chrome: http://forums.asp.net/t/1894299.aspx?XMLHttpRequest+responseXML+text+not+Working+In+Google+Chrome+Firefox+Opera

Comment: if I do that, then even firefox stops showing the content, let alone chrome.

Comment: there is a solution for this.. Is this html page run on server(like tomcat) or local desktop without any server?

Comment: local desktop.. I think IIS Express.. If that what you mean.